# Combine Label.Text into ASP.Net Html Code

Tags: html, asp.net, label

```
<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="+905554443322" Font-Size="Small"></asp:Label>

<a class="float" href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + "Label4.Text" target="_blank"> <i class="fa fa-whatsapp my-float"></i>
```

Dear members of the forum.
In my ASP.Net work, I want to bring the text value of label4 to the place inside the link. I just couldn't make it.

So I want to bring the text value of Label4 to the relevant place in the web.whatsapp link. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not quite clear, but since the lable is a server side control, then make the hyper link also server side.

Eg this:

```
        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="+905554443322" 
            Font-Size="Small"></asp:Label>

       <a class="float" id="MyRef" runat="server" href="" target="_blank"> 
           <i class="fa fa-whatsapp my-float"></i>
        </a>
```

So, on page load, then set the href value:

```
Private Sub form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles form1.Load

    MyRef.HRef = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + Label4.Text

End Sub
```